# Asymptotic analaysis nlogn vs. n

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory

[image of code that is analyzed for asymptotic runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCp4b.png)

I was given a problem of analyzing the runtime of this code, and I came up with NlogN since the outerloop is Logn and the innerloop is N, so the loops multiply out to NlogN. However, the solution says this is incorrect and says the actual runtime of this code is O(n) due to the inner loop running on O(n), but for some reason the loops don't multiply so Logn is dropped due to it being lower order?

Can someone help me out on understanding this? Why is LogN + N instead of LogN * N?

Comment: I think you are correct, NlogN. https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is a better community for this type of thing, I would ask there. It's possible that your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's count how many time the instruction sum++ is triggered

in the first loop of while it will be triggered 2^0 = 1
in the second one 2^1 = 2 ,in the third it is 2^2 = 4 and ..so on
in the loop number var loop it will be triggered 2^var times

so the overall count is
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^var ,which is equal to 2^(var+1) - 1

now our problem is to find out the value of var, it is obviously log(N)
so the overall is 2^(log(N)+1) - 1, which is O(N)